# Uninstalling an app from phones of users who have already installed former version

Tags: android, ios, store, playback

One year ago I contracted with an App Development company. They made me an app. But because of some reasons I deleted our app from app markets. Now I want to deploy new version which we develop with another company. But former company losted app keys and I am not able to delete obsolete apps which already installed on users phone. How I can uninstall obsolete version of my app from users phone?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot remove an app from people's phones.  Only they can remove the app from their own devices.

If you can use the same bundle id (on iOS) or equivalent app identifier on Android then your new version will be an update to the existing app and will replace the old app.

Comment: This should be common sense to realize. Unless the app has super powers, i.e. root privileges or something.

Comment: The other problem is, even we can find the app identifier key, we may not fix the uninstall old app problem with updating. Because old version was developed native and new version developed hybrid(flutter). Namely app identifier may not fit with new platform. So, I wonder whether someone updated their native app with flutter app also.

Comment: It doesn't matter what technology you use. When the app is updated the executable code is replaced. The data remains but your new version can just ignore that.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to do this unless you have access to their phones. If you know the users of the app then you can message them to delete the app if you have their contact info. If the other app is installed on their phone, it probably won't hurt for them to keep the app, and install the new one. Delete the other version off the app store, and put the new app up :D